# Django trailing slashes in urls are not working correctly

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing

While testing my django app I'm receiving 302 status code instead of 200. In manual check I discovered that initially instead of slash at the end of url browser doesn't see it and redirects to url with trailing slash.

Part of urls.py:

```
path('add/', add_product, name='add_product')
```

Function which tests it:

```
    def test_add_product_view_pass(self):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='test_user', 
                                             email='test_user_email@email.com')
        user.set_password('test')
        user.save()
        c = Client()
        response = c.post(reverse('log_in'), {'username': 'test_user', 'password': 
                                              'test'})
        user = get_user(c)
        self.assertTrue(user.username, 'test_user')
        self.assertEqual(user.is_superuser, True)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('add_product'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

So basically I need to log superuser to have access to this part of app. There's form which allows to create model object. APPEND_SLASH is on default True setting.
After running this test I'm getting AssertionError: 302 != 200.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is, but I'll try to explain a little bit about the 302. If the url in the browser doesn't match any of the patterns in your `urls.py`, and if `APPEND_SLASH` is `True`, it will redirect to the same url after adding a trailing slash. If it finds a match (which it will in your example), then it will go to the correct page. It will return a status code of 302, so that the user will know there has been a redirect. If you had typed the url in the browser with a trailing slash, there would have been no need for a redirect and it would have returned a 200.

Comment: The problem is that, in urls.py and in my templates both urls got trailing slash. And I still have situation where django first tries to get url without slash, and after that redirects to the same one but with slash at the end.